# Error: DatabaseBridge is null using WatermelonDB in react-native

Tags: react-native, expo, watermelondb

I am new to react native. While creating an app, I have encountered an error which says *"null is not an object."* I have researched throughout the internet but haven't come to a solution yet.

I am using `expo` and `watermelondb`.

**error**

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'DatabaseBridge[methodName]')
```

[image: it says null is not an object]

**App.js**

```
import { AppRegistry } from "react-native";
import { name as appName } from "./app.json";

import { Database } from "@nozbe/watermelondb";
import SQLiteAdapter from "@nozbe/watermelondb/adapters/sqlite";
import { mySchema } from "./app/models/schema";
import { dbModels } from "./app/models/index.js";

// Added new import
import { createNavigation } from "./app/screens/Navigation";

// First, create the adapter to the underlying database:
const adapter = new SQLiteAdapter({
  dbName: "StudentTable",
  schema: mySchema
});

// Then, make a Watermelon database from it!
const database = new Database({
  adapter,
  modelClasses: dbModels
});


const Navigation = createNavigation({ database });

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => Navigation);
```

**Navigation**

```
import React from "react";
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';

import Root from "./Root";
import Student from "./Student";
import Tution from "./Tution";

export const createNavigation = props =>
  createAppContainer(
    createStackNavigator(
      {
        Root: {
          // We have to use a little wrapper because React Navigation doesn't pass simple props (and withObservables needs that)
          screen: ({ navigation }) => {
            const { database } = props;
            return <Root database={database} navigation={navigation} />;
          },
          navigationOptions: { title: "Students" }
        },
        Student: {
          screen: ({ navigation }) => (
            <Student
              student={navigation.state.params.student}
              navigation={navigation}
            />
          ),
          navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            StudentName: navigation.state.params.student.StudentName
          })
        },
        NewStudent: {
          screen: ({ navigation }) => {
            const { database } = props;
            return <Tution database={database} navigation={navigation} />;
          },
          navigationOptions: { title: "New Student" }
        },
        EditStudent: {
          screen: ({ navigation }) => {
            return (
              <MovieForm
                student={navigation.state.params.student}
                navigation={navigation}
              />
            );
          },
          navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            title: `Edit "${navigation.state.params.student.StudentName}"`
          })
        }
      },
      {
        initialRouteName: "Root",
        initialRouteParams: props
      }
    )
  );
```

**The file i suspect Tution.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Button,
  Container,
  Content,
  Form,
  Item,
  Input,
  Label,
  Textarea,
  Picker,
  Body,
  Text,
  DatePicker
} from "native-base";
import {RadioButton} from "react-native-paper"
import { studentStd } from "../models/randomData";
import { date } from "@nozbe/watermelondb/decorators";

class Tution extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
      toggle:true,
    }
    if (props.student) {
      this.state = { ...props.student.getStudent() };
    } else {
      this.state = {};
    }
  }


  render() {
    const [checked,setChecked]=React.useState('Bank')
    return (
      <Container>
        <Content>
          <Form>
            <Item floatingLabel>
              <Label>StudentName</Label>
              <Input
                onChangeText={StudentName => this.setState({ StudentName })}
                value={this.state.StudentName}
              />
            </Item>
            <View style={{ paddingLeft: 15 }}>
              <Item picker>
                <Picker
                  mode="dropdown"
                  style={{ width: undefined, paddingLeft: 15 }}
                  placeholder="Std"
                  placeholderStyle={{ color: "#bfc6ea" }}
                  placeholderIconColor="#007aff"
                  selectedValue={this.state.Std}
                  onValueChange={Std => this.setState({ Std })}
                >
                  {studentStd.map((Std, i) => (
                    <Picker.Item key={i} label={Std} value={Std} />
                  ))}
                </Picker>
              </Item>
            </View>


            <View style={{ paddingLeft: 15, marginTop: 15 }}>
              <Text style={{ color: "gray" }}>Date</Text>
              <DatePicker
                locale={"en"}
                animationType={"fade"}
                androidMode={"default"}
                placeHolderText="Date"
                defaultDate={new Date()}
                onDateChange={FeesDate => this.setState({ FeesDate })}
              />
              <Text>
                {this.state.date &&
                  this.state.date.toString().substr(4, 12)}
              </Text>

              <Text style={{ color: "gray", marginTop: 15 }}>Bank/Cash</Text>
              <Textarea
                rowSpan={5}
                bordered
                placeholder="Bank/Cash"
                onChangeText={bankorcash => this.setState({ bankorcash })}
                value={this.state.bankorcash}
              />

<Text style={{ color: "gray", marginTop: 15 }}>Rtgs No</Text>
              <Textarea
                rowSpan={5}
                bordered
                placeholder="rtgsno"
                onChangeText={rtgsno => this.setState({ rtgsno })}
                value={this.state.rtgsno}
              />
              <Text style={{ color: "gray", marginTop: 15 }}>Received Amt</Text>
              <Textarea
                rowSpan={5}
                bordered
                placeholder="Received Amt"
                onChangeText={recd => this.setState({ recd })}
                value={this.state.recd}
              />
              <Text style={{ color: "gray", marginTop: 15 }}>Pending</Text>
              <Textarea
                rowSpan={5}
                bordered
                placeholder="Pending"
                onChangeText={pending => this.setState({ pending })}
                value={this.state.pending}
              />
                    <Text style={{ color: "gray", marginTop: 15 }}>Days Attended</Text>
              <Textarea
                rowSpan={5}
                bordered
                placeholder="Days"
                onChangeText={daysattended => this.setState({ daysattended })}
                value={this.state.daysattended}
              />
            </View>
            

            <Body>
              <Button onPress={this.handleSubmit}>
                <Text>{this.props.student ? "Update " : "Add "} Movie</Text>
              </Button>
            </Body>
          </Form>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }

  handleSubmit = () => {
    if (this.props.student) {
      this.handleUpdateStudent();
    } else {
      this.handleAddNewStudent();
    }
  };

  handleAddNewStudent = async () => {
    const { database } = this.props;
    const students = database.collections.get("students");
    const newStudent = await movies.create(student => {
      student.StudentName=this.state.StudentName,
      student.Std=this.state.Std,
      student.bankorcash=this.state.bankorcash,
      student.rtgsno=this.state.rtgsno,
      student.recd=this.state.recd,
      student.pending=this.state.pending,
      student.daysattended=this.state.daysattended,
      student.date=this.state.date
    });
    this.props.navigation.goBack();
  };

  handleUpdateStudent = async () => {
    const { student } = this.props;
    await student.updateStudent({
      StudentName:this.state.StudentName,
      Std:this.state.Std,
    bankorcash:this.state.bankorcash,
     rtgsno:this.state.rtgsno,
      recd:this.state.recd,
     pending:this.state.pending,
    daysattended:this.state.daysattended,
   date:this.state.date
    });
    this.props.navigation.goBack();
  };
}

export default Tution;
```

**Navigation.js** :

import React from "react";
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";

```
import Root from "./Root";
import Student from "./Student";
import Tution from "./Tution";

export const createNavigation = props =>
  createAppContainer(
    createStackNavigator(
      {
        Root: {
          // We have to use a little wrapper because React Navigation doesn't pass simple props (and withObservables needs that)
          screen: ({ navigation }) => {
            const { database } = props;
            return <Root database={database} navigation={navigation} />;
          },
          navigationOptions: { title: "Students" }
        },
        Student: {
          screen: ({ navigation }) => (
            <Student
              student={navigation.state.params.student}
              navigation={navigation}
            />
          ),
          navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            StudentName: navigation.state.params.student.StudentName
          })
        },
        NewStudent: {
          screen: ({ navigation }) => {
            const { database } = props;
            return <Tution database={database} navigation={navigation} />;
          },
          navigationOptions: { title: "New Student" }
        },
        EditStudent: {
          screen: ({ navigation }) => {
            return (
              <StudentForm
                student={navigation.state.params.student}
                navigation={navigation}
              />
            );
          },
          navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            title: `Edit "${navigation.state.params.student.StudentName}"`
          })
        }
      },
      {
        initialRouteName: "Root",
        initialRouteParams: props
      }
    )
  );
```

Comment: The error is not from your component code.  It's a problem with the configuration.  Somewhere in the setup a `DatabaseBridge` was supposed to be created, but it wasn't. `NativeModules.DatabaseBridge is not defined! This means that you haven't properly linked WatermelonDB native module. Refer to docs for more details`

Comment: https://nozbe.github.io/WatermelonDB/Installation.html

Comment: After looking further, it seems like you cannot use WatermelonDB with expo.  See [here](https://github.com/Nozbe/WatermelonDB/issues/310) [here](https://github.com/Nozbe/WatermelonDB/issues/40) and [here](https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/add-support-for-watermelondb).

Comment: Ma'am i am aware it doesnt work with expo to be precise it does work after ejecting with expo i need this db to make the application offline first since i am new to this i also am researching more and more but thank you i will look into the installation files and let you know

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue as I'd missed the NodeJS setup in the docs.

You need to install better-sqlite3:

`yarn add --dev better-sqlite3`

or

`npm install -D better-sqlite3`

Comment: This did not fix it for me. Could there be any other reasons?